# Scroll horizontally pop-ups

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to scroll and show pop-ups one time in their predefined interval, but I have some trouble with the  `for`  iteration. It is not working and the pop-ups are overlapping from the first to last.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Y7g3/14/

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){

       var popWidth = "44%";
       var popHeight = "30%";




function pop(popID){ $('#' + popID)
       .fadeIn().css({ 'width': String( popWidth ), 'height': String( popHeight ) })
       .prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');
};



function block(box, top, left, color){

$("#container").append('<div id="'+box+'"></div>');
$('#' +box).css("background-color", color).animate({top: top ,left: left });
};

var popup=['#popup1','#popup2','#popup3','#popup4','#popup5','#popup6','#popup7','#popup8'];

var range = $(this).scrollLeft();

    if( range > 500 && range < 600){

           pop('popup1');

           for (var i=0; i<popup.lenght; i++ ){

               if (popup[i]!='#popup1'){

               $(popup[i]).fadeOut(function() {$(popup[i]).hide();});

               };   
           };


           block('box1','84%','10%','#f04');

    }

    if(range > 1500 && range < 1600){

           pop('popup2');

           for (var i=0; i<popup.lenght; i++ ){

               if (popup[i]!='#popup2'){

                    $(popup[i]).fadeOut(function() {$(popup[i]).hide();});

               };  
            };

           block('box2','84%','17%','yellow');
     };

     if(range > 2500 && range < 2600){

           pop('popup3');

           //$('#popup1').fadeOut(function() {$('#popup1').hide(); });

           block('box3','84%','24%','blue');
   };
```

Comment: What actually are you trying to achieve here? You told us what's not working, but you haven't said, what you expect.

Comment: For starters you've misspelt `length` in your `for` loop: `for (var i=0; i<popup.lenght; i++ ){...`, should be `for (var i=0; i<popup.length; i++ ){...`.

That error would be shown if you checked with FireBug / Chrome developer tools etc.

Comment: Sorry, i'm using Eclipse .